# No bold, italic and small caps with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I switched my working document from pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX. I have a problem with the font, because now Computer Modern Roman doesn't display bold, italic and small caps text (it works only in one page if I say `\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont`).

Ex in my images caption, I've said in preamble `labelfont={sc,color=blue}, textfont={small,it}, labelsep=endash` what is working except for it and sc. And `\textit`, `\textbf`, `\textsc` are not working in all the document :

[image]

This is a MWE :

```
%%Classe du document
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[labelfont={sc,color=blue}, textfont={small,it}, labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ } 

%%Pour insérer des images
\usepackage{graphicx} 

%%Le document est en français
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage{cmlgc}

\begin{document}
{\huge\textsc{Sans la liberté de blâmer, il n'est point d'éloge flatteur. }}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Beaumarchais}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do not use T1 and fontenc encoding with xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I tried but it didn't changed anything...

Comment: similarly you don't want all those `\usefont{T1}...` T1 is a legacy 8bit encoding it removes all the features of xetex if you use that, you may as well stay with pdftex.

Comment: unrelated but `book` does not have an `article` option what do you intend it to do?

Comment: Your example code should _provide an example of the problem_ you have provided nearly 300 lines of something but since it isn't a complete document and has no text it does not demonstrate anything or allow anyone to debug. Can you make a _much_ smaller document that does not load all the unrelated packages (do you really need to load tikz to show a problem with bold fonts?)  and makes some text that you think should be in some font but appears in another. then someone can run it and debug.

Comment: Please provide a Minimum Working Example rather than a large fragment of preamble which people cannot compile.

Comment: @cfr, I made the requested edits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've made your requested edits.

Comment: hmm I get loads of warnings like `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`EU1/fcm/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/fcm/m/n' instead on input line 24.` which says that latex can not do italic so will use normal shape instead. where did `fcm` family come from?? Is that part of the french setup? I'll look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like cmlgc package is not compatible with Unicode fonts as used by xetex, if I remove that the font warnings go and you get small caps output

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[labelfont={sc,color=blue}, textfont={small,it}, labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ } 

%%Pour insérer des images
\usepackage{graphicx} 

%%Le document est en français
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

%\usepackage{cmlgc}

\begin{document}
{\huge\textsc{Sans la liberté de blâmer, il n'est point d'éloge flatteur. }}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Beaumarchais}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```